# Insert 1:N relationship from iOS Azure Mobile Services

Tags: ios, azure-mobile-services

I have a offline sync enabled table Search that 1:N relationship with couple of tables like Criteria and Results. I want to insert Search object that contains it's fields and criteria object and results.

Here's my code:

```
NSDictionary *criteria = nil; //suppose it have keys and values
NSArray *results = nil; //array of dictionary
NSDictionary *item = @{@"title": @"Huray", @"userId":@"Facebook:1231231231232", @"favourite":@NO, @"criteria":criteria, @"results": results};

[self.searchService addItem:item completion:nil];
```

I know that I have to write some [scripts](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2013/08/23/complex-types-and-azure-mobile-services.aspx) for the Node.js backend and if my backend is .NET then I probably wouldn't have to write custom code but what do I have to do for local store

```
-(void)insert:(NSDictionary *)item completion:(MSSyncItemBlock)completion;
```

insert method only insert and send search table fields both on local store and server. What do I have to do to insert Search table with relationship on both local store and server?

Comment: Did you found out how it works ? I'm also looking for same.

Comment: @Preetham nope. Do let me know if you found one.

Comment: @user2290194 Still no answer?

Comment: @Hugo still nothing.